# Create an order purchase in SharePoint

Tags: list, lookup-column

I'm a newbie in SharePoint and I need advice. I would like to use SharePoint 2013 to manage order purchases assuming that each order can have multiple products related.

Due to SharePoint do not support a list inside a list, I think the solution is to create a list for the Orders requests and another list for the Products (of the order) and link each product with an Order ID. After that, I can create a view or page that join Source Data from both lists.

Is a better way to do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check the [following blog](http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/create-purchase-order-using-collection-column/), He created the purchase with using two lists with collection column.

- Purchase order list contains order details, includes Purchase Order, Status, Purchase Date, Purchaser, Total Amount and Equipment.
- And Equipment list records equipment details, includes Number, Equipment, Model, Brand and Price.

There is 3rd party template available, you can use that or check it for idea.

http://www.convergepoint.com/sharepoint-templates/purchase-order-system-sharepoint-template

Comment: The options that you propose me are great but are all pay options. Another option could be fill an order form using a repeating section for each product, isn't it?  But I suppose that later I should transfer this information to a list to be able to display all orders in one single table.